# Remove HashMap braces around values in Spring HttpRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, httprequest

So I'm a pretty unexperienced programmer and doing a project for my university java course.
Basic Login program where login data is stored in a mysql database on the server and accessed through HttpRequests from the client.
I'm trying to send a HashMap through a HttpRequest

```
public static boolean checkPassword(String username, String password, String url) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(password, username);
    boolean check = false;

    try {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080"+url+map))
                .build();

        HttpResponse response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
            if (response.body().toString().equals("true")) {
                check = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return check;
}
```

My RestController method looks like this

```
@GetMapping(path = "users/findPasswordByUsername", produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> findExistingPasswordByUsername(@RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> map) {
    String password = String.valueOf(map.keySet());
    String username = String.valueOf(map.values());
    return userService.findPasswordByUsername(password, username);
}
```

When trying to send the HttpRequest i get the following:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 51: http://localhost:8080/users/findPasswordByUsername/{test=exampleuser}
```

Anybody got an answer on how I remove the braces around the hashmap values?

Comment: That code is just wrong, that is **not** how you would get the username or password from a map. What you now have is the `toString` representation of a `Set`. Why aren't you just sending parameters like everyone else, or even better use Basic or Digest Authentication for http. And finally instead of building your own, I would strongly suggest to ditch all of that and use Spring Security instead.

Comment: So how do I get the string values from a map?

Comment: a Map is a key/value pair. You should just submit a regular request parameter which has a name and a value and send 2. But as stated you are building your own security solution, don't use something proven like Spring Security, Apache Shiro etc. Also if this is for a university project, don't store passwords, store hashes and validate against the hash. Send 2 parameters username and password not both like that or just use Basic Authentication which is a default mechanism to send username/password in HTTP. Either way don't reinvent the wheel.